# Can not get radio button value from Wordpress general settings

Tags: php, wordpress

Constantly i am getting below errors when print to display radio button value from wordpress general settings:

> Illegal string offset 'service' in F:\wamp\www\plugin-tester\wp-content\themes\twentythirteen\functions.php on line 565
>
> Illegal string offset 'service' in F:\wamp\www\plugin-tester\wp-content\themes\twentythirteen\functions.php on line 568

Here is my code which i added in function.php file:

```
add_filter('admin_init', 'myservice_register_function');
function myservice_register_function(){

register_setting('general', 'my_service', 'esc_attr');

add_settings_field('my_service', '<label for="service_need">'.__('Do You need My    Service' , 'my_service' ).'</label>' , 'service_function', 'general');
}

 function service_function(){
   $options = get_option( 'my_service', '');
   //  $options = get_settings( 'my_service');

   if($options['service'] == 'YES') { //line number 565
     echo 'Yes, Service Need'; 
   }
  if($options['service'] == 'NO') { // line number 568
    echo 'No Need Service';
}


  $html = '<input type="radio"  name="my_service[service]" value="YES"/>'; 
  $html .= '<label> NEED </label>'; 
     
  $html .= '<input type="radio"  name="my_service[service]" value="NO"/>'; 
  $html .= '<label > NO NEED </label>'; 
     
  echo $html;
 }
```

Please help somebody and indicate my code where i do mistake.

Comment: esc_attr seems not to work with radio buttons, using esc_sql does the job..and I have come to solve this problem with below line: `register_setting('general', 'my_service', 'esc_sql');`   i/o `register_setting('general', 'my_service', 'esc_attr');`

Answer (score 1):

Its likely that your $options variable is a string, not an array.  When you write `$options['arrayKey']`, you're treating $options as an array.

Make a debug function:

```
function my_debug($o){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($o);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

And call that on your $options variable around line 563-564:

```
my_debug($options);
```

You'll see what it looks like, whether its a string or an array, and whether it has a "service" key, like you're checking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($options == 'YES') { //line number 565
     echo 'Yes, Service Need'; 
   }
  if($options == 'NO') { // line number 568
    echo 'No Need Service';
}
```

get_option returns `value` of the `key` you pass in it and boolean `false` in case key not find. you are interpreting value as an array

**refer here** [**`Get Option`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)